# Как сделать, чтобы по вводу в инпут одного символа (любого) функция отрабатывала один раз?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

сейчас отрабатывает постоянно ( видно по консоли)

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keydown', function() {
  console.log('test');
})
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: не ясно. то есть нужно чтобы в инпут можно было ввести только один символ что ли? или что?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Однократное срабатывание функции достигается передачей в третьем аргументе обработчика объекта *[options](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B)* с ключом *once* и значением *true*:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keydown', function() {
  console.log('test');
}, { once: true })
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Если же нужно, чтобы действие происходило однократно, но каждый раз при вводе первого символа, то необходимо добавить простейшее условие:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keydown', function() {
  if (this.value == '') console.log('test');
})
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Предположу что нужен `keyup`

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  console.log('test');
})
```

```html
<input type="text">
```